# WebView deallocated when removed form container view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I am working on MAC OSX 10.10 Yosemite
My problem is, I have a webview, which when removed from the container deallocates the webView object  thus the youtube video present in webview stops.
Why does removing a webview from its container deallocates it ?

I have following code

```
@interface AppDelegate () {
    WebView *myWebView;
}
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *container;
@end
```

---

And its implementation

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    myWebView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20, 20, 600, 480)];
    myWebView.mainFrameURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/";

    [_container addSubview:myWebView];
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(NSButton *)sender {
    [myWebView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

What changes should I make so that removing the webview from container does not stops the youtube video ?

Comment: what I understand from your question you are reproducing an youtube video in a webview and you want to remove the webview but keeping the video playing, am I right?

Comment: @tkanzakic Yes. In this case the video will disappear, but the audio of the video will continue to play.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible, this sounds to me like turn off the TV but listen the audio, but you can try to make your TV "very smaller" ;), like 1x1 and behind an other control

Comment: You could look to it this way: Putting a cover on TV, stops playing TV, because no one can see it. (TV should/will work as long it is plugged in and not being turned off by a remote(deallocate) no matter if it is visible or not)

Comment: removing the webview is not like putting a cover, making it very smaller and/or putting an other component over it is, so my suggestion is that instead of making a `removeFromSuperview` just resize it and put another component over it (like an `UIView` of the same color of the background)

Comment: Analogies are subjective. Lets not discuss that. Do you have the solution(not a hack) for my requirement ?

Comment: for the 3rd time: so my suggestion is that instead of making a `removeFromSuperview` just resize it and put another component over it (like an `UIView` of the same color of the background)